# Loop through text fields array and check if ALL are empty

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, nsarray, enumeration

Im looping through an array of `UITextFields` and checking if any of them are empty

```
NSArray*textFields = ...;


textFieldHasData = YES;
[textFields enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj isEqualToString:@""]) {
        textFieldHasData = NO;
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];
if (!textFieldHasData) {
    //Empty text fields found
}
```

I also want to check if **ALL** the `textfields` are empty in the array,  rather than individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse the logic:

```
NSArray *textFields = ...;

textFieldHasData = NO;
[textFields enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UITextField *field, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([[field text] length] > 0) {
        textFieldHasData = YES;
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];
if (!textFieldHasData) {
    // All text fields are empty

}
```